# Looping Hashmap in jenkins file and passing keys to shell or powershell or bat, Not working

Tags: shell, jenkins, hashmap, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins file where I am trying to loop over one ***Array*** and passing its **elements** to Shell script block, It is Working Fine
But, when I am Looping over ***Hashmap*** and trying to pass Its **Keys** it throws an error.

```
stage('Validation'){
        steps{
            script{ 
                test1 = ["elem1","elem2"]
                test2 = [key1:"value1", key2:"value2"]
                                   
                for(defaults in test1){
                    test=defaults
                    echo "before shell====> ${test}"
                    status = sh(returnStdout: true,  script: """
                        echo "${test}"
                    """).trim() 
                }
                echo "======started next HashMAP loop==========="
                for(defaults in test2){
                    test=defaults.key
                    echo "before shell====> ${test}"
                    status = sh(returnStdout: true,  script: """
                        echo "${test}"
                    """).trim() 
                }
          }
     }
 }
```

Where the output:

[image]

Last Error :

> Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry

Comment: Have you tried the "forEach" statement? See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When I replace the second loop over hashmap entries like this:

```
test2.each{ entry ->
    test=entry.key
    echo "before shell====> ${test}"
    status = sh(returnStdout: true,  script: """
        echo "${test}"
    """).trim()
}
```

I get the following output:

[image: Jenkins pipeline output]

That was probably what you wanted. For some reason the "for each" loop does not trigger serialization, like stated in comments of [JENKINS-49732](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-49732)